# Is there a close form for $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^3}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Is there a close form for $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^3}dx$ ?

I tried numerical method and find that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^3}dx=0.892979$$  but, my question is that "does it have a closed form solution ?" 
thanks in advanced .

Comment: yes there is $$\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Depending on whether you define the Gamma function as a "closed form" or just a rewriting of an integral. But I don't think it can be done any better.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(e%5E(-x%5E3),x%3D0..infinity)

Comment: Isn't it $$\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x^3} dx = \frac{1}{3} \int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{1/3 - 1}e^{-t} dx = \frac{1}{3} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$$?

Comment: @user8469759 Yes, but $\Gamma(x + 1) = x\Gamma(x)$.

Comment: @user49640 I missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u=x^3$ to get

$$I=\frac13\int_0^\infty u^{-2/3}e^{-u}~\mathrm du=\frac13\Gamma(1/3)=\Gamma(4/3)$$

where $\Gamma(x)$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) or an [Euler integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_integral).

As given [in this PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403510v1.pdf) we find that

$$\Gamma(4/3)=\frac{\pi^{1/3}2^{7/9}}{3^{13/12}}\mathrm K\left(\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2^{3/2}}\right)^{1/3}$$

Where $\mathrm K(x)$ is a [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind).